(═ Exception caught by gesture═Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator ═ )this error is coming(elevated button)
i am trying to make a navigating for my tutorial and this error is coming.
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

and this is my code
main.dart
import 'profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Home",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30)),
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[100],
        ),
        body: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Profile())
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Navigate to profile")),
      ),
    );
  }
}


profile.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Profile({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Home",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30)),
          toolbarHeight: 70,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[100],
        ),
        body: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()));
            },
            child: const Text("Navigate to home")),
      ),
    );
  }
}


the elevated button is not working

why dont you use runApp(MaterialApp(... pattern? i mean remove MaterialApp from Home widget and place it in top level context

Does this answer your question? Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator
